# Does these file structural change official in asp.net core 1.1 compared to asp.net core 1.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have seen lot of tutorial and articles online regarding .NET CORE 1.0(because there are no much detail articles on version 1.1)

Apart for many advantages there were **lot of changes in file structure.**

But when I created application in **.NET CORE 1.1 and ASP.NET MVC 1.1.** I realized that there are **lot of changes in files structures compared to .NET CORE 1.0 file structure**(Few files are missing and few folders are missing)

**Files missing in .NET CORE 1.1 from .NET CORE 1.0:**

1. project.json
2. global.json
3. package.json

**Question 1:** In few articles I read project.json is replaced with new .csproj file. But I think package.json and project.json are combined as .csproj file because I can see npm references in .csproj file. Am I right?

**Question 2:** I cant find the reference of sdk components "Microsoft.NETCORE.App" in any file which will be usually defined in global.json file in .NET CORE 1.0. Now in .NET CORE 1.1 I can find global.json file. Then where is the reference is mentioned? I think without mentioning a reference the sdk package will not load.

**Folders missing in .NET CORE 1.1 from .NET CORE 1.0:**

1. Src folder
2. Solution files folder

**Question 3:** Are these folders officially removed from the projects file structure?

**Question 4:** Are these folders and files optional? Personally I feel very good and less confused with this files not being there.

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: @PhilipKendall The basic question is there are changes in project files structure from asp.net core 1.0 to 1.1. The sub 4 questions are in detail and highly related to same question and I can't put 4 posts for each question because if I do that it will be a difficult task for the future users to get clarified regarding this question.

Comment: With VisualStudio 2017 project.json is replaced with .csproj file. The csproj file contains `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>` element which tells what framework the app is targeting (or `TargetFrameworks` if you want to target muliple frameworks)